# How to create an external List on SharePoint 2010 using MySQL table

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, bdc-model, business-data-catalog

I have a **MYSQL** database that contains *customer related data* from sugarcrm while a few order related data is stored in the MSSQL server.

So far, I have been able to create an external list for the orders using SPD and external content types leveraging BDC for SP 2010 . But regarding MySQL , I am slightly lost as it seems there are no apparent straightforward ways to do this.

Googled my way to land up in a few places where people either wrote some piece of BCS code or used some third party solution. If someone has tried the same before, kindly share the approach as it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are after. You are saying that you found some places where people wrote piece of BCS ? Why doesn't that work for you?

Here is a very good explained guide that I used to connect MySQL with BCS:

[http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=632](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=640)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link helps.

http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/09/02/mysql-and-business-connectivity-services-using-bcs-meta-man.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the solution, however I had seen this link before and as mentioned in my question I am looking for approach (precisely the steps and logic behind). Third party solutions are there but even those solutions work with a certain logic. I am looking for the same.